# Android : Error Snack bar not showing correctly with Map View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-snackbar, mapbox-android, snackbar

this is xml layout

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_location_picker_main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is the output :

[image]

I am using a **CoordinatorLayout** as a root of my **xml file** and **mapbox** layout for showing the map.
I don't know what is happening please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a view on top of MapView and show snackbar within it :))

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/snackbarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity:

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(snackbarView, "Message :))", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
snackbar.show()
```

Comment: thanks it seems clever solution but i can't test it because i left the company that i worked for from a while.

Comment: unfortunately this solution did not work for me (Also using coordinator layout with a map view)